# Records disappearing in PDO mssql transaction loop

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, transactions, pdo

I have the following code (more or less) to import anywhere from 500.000 to 4.000.000 rows:

```
$sSql = "Insert into table (a,b,c) VALUES(?,?,?)"
$oSQLStmnt = $pdo->prepare($sSql);
$oSQLStmnt->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM);
if (!$oSQLStmnt) {
    echo $pdo->errorInfo(); // Handle errors
}
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$iLineCounter = 1;
while (($sLine = fgets ($oCSV, 8000)) !== FALSE) {
      $aLine = explode('|', $sLine); //Fgetscsv did not work properly 
       if ($iLineCounter % 100 == 0) {
            lo("Inserting row " . $iLineCounter);
            $pdo->commit();
            sleep(0.15);
            $pdo->beginTransaction();
       }
       try {
            $oSQLStmnt->execute($aLine);
            $iSuccesulInserts++;
       }
       catch (exception $e) {
            print_r($e);
            $iFailedInserts++;
       }

       $iLineCounter++;
}
$pdo->commit();
```

As you can see, I perform a commit every 100 lines, and I even added some sleep. I used to run the commit only once every 25.000 lines, and I did not use any sleep. However, at one point, I discovered I was missing records. I started playing with these settings (sleep and number of rows). This way I reduced the number of missing records from 50.000 to about a 100. But I'm still missing records! Where are they going? I know the SQL is ok, because I immediately receive errors when somethings wrong there.

I thought I could stack a lot of inserts during a transaction? Could calling beginTransaction be a problem?

**UPDATE:**

The bounty ended and I had to award it. Thank you all for your answers. Or tips actually, as none of you actually answered my question. I was not asking for a workaround, although you suggestions are much appreciated. The answer the bounty was awarded to received it because it came closest to actually answering my question. Unfortunately it did not work.

For now I'm using CSV bulk import, that works fine, but if anyone has any other tips for fixing this issue, please let me know. As I prefer using my original method.

Comment: Running the code without beginTransaction and stacking all insert queries in one transaction results in the disappearance of about 40.000 records...

Comment: If I repeat this loop without transactions, it works just fine. No records lost...

Comment: The problem is not caused by PDO. That's for sure.

Comment: Id try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx as theres a lot of data there

Comment: You mean importing a CSV file directly in SQL? That would mean I would have to read the CSV file, clean it up, write it back to another CSV, and insert that in de DB. I Could do that, but it does not feel very efficient.

Comment: Are you certain that your home-brewn CSV parser is not the problem? If you simplify the problem to inserting the array ("a$i", "b$i", "c$i") for every $i in `range(0, 50000)` and remove all the problematic code (sleeps, `try .. catch`, and intermediate commits), can you still reproduce the problem? If yes, can you link to a [*complete* example script](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Possible exceptions from `$pdo->commit();` and `$pdo->beginTransaction();` are not being caught with such code, if I read it correctly.

Comment: Phi:As stated, when I leave out the transaction, everything is slow but fine, no missing records, so no problems with my CSV parser.
VYE: What exceptions? I thought that those exceptions would rise as I execute the query. Also, when I slow things down, I lose less records, so uncaught errors in SQL are not the issue.

Comment: The script in `$sSql` is missing the `VALUES` keyword. Is that word also missing from the script in your working code?

Comment: ¿does commit and begintansactioan always returns true? ¿the missing records are correlative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Sprocs instead of insert statements? writing ANY number of records sequentially- one at a time- is kindof a waste of time / energy.. it's just not as fast as it should be.

Are you sure you can't use BULK INSERT or XML instead to insert multiple rows at a time?

Comment: That's what i'm doing right now as a workaround. But I think it's just awful that records are disappearing without any notice...

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem before. For me, I had to do a "SET NOCOUNT ON" before the INSERTS because SQL Server was trying to return me "One row added" for each INSERT and it message queue was full and it just stoped inserting data, without returning any errors!

So you should definitely try to do a "SET NOCOUNT ON" before the INSERTS.
I bet it's gonna fix your problem.

Comment: That sounds totally plausible! Gonna try it today!

Comment: Before every insert statement or just once?

Comment: Does not solve it unfortunately. '14:57:10[119] | RESULT FOR table: Total lines: 466792Succesful: 466789 Failed: 2 '  -> `select count(*) from table` = `441925`

Answer (score 3):

You use sleep () 0.15 seconds to delay the execution, however, question:
What happens if the INSERT take longer than 0.15 seconds? The script to run back and the table may be blocked because of previous commit.

Then try an approach of multiple INSERT's in a single run in the database. Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO example (example_id, name, value, other_value)VALUES
(100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'), (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
(102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'), (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

To achieve this, do:

```
$sql = ' INSERT INTO example (example_id, name, value, other_value)VALUES';
while (($sLine = fgets ($oCSV, 8000)) !== FALSE) {
    // generate VALUES to INSERT in a $sql .= '(..., ..., ...),'
}
```

And then run!

Answer (score 2):

@Saratis,

Have you considered creating a simple sproc which performs the desired action using a MERGE?  Merging will consume some considerable overhead, however, I've always known it to be a very reliable way to synchronize records from a 'master' data source to a dependent data source.

I am of the philosophy that the Database should control HOW data is used, and the code should control WHEN the database does what it does.  What I prefer to do is keep anything which touches data in a stored proc, and call stored procs with code when certain conditions/events happen.  However, your situation could be unique enough that this is not exactly a best practice.

The below code snippet comes from Microsoft as an example of how to accomplish a merge:

```
MERGE Production.UnitMeasure AS target
USING (SELECT @UnitMeasureCode, @Name) AS source (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
ON (target.UnitMeasureCode = source.UnitMeasureCode)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET Name = source.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
    VALUES (source.UnitMeasureCode, source.Name)
    OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO #MyTempTable;
```

Here is the link to the whole article, which covers a few different scenarios:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Now, to get the information into the SQL Server from a CSV, the following link explains how that can be achieved using the file path as the part of the FROM clause, and specifying the delimiter in a WITH clause.

It covers BULK INSERT also, if that may work best for you, however, I am partial to the MERGE because it handles both INSERT for new records and UPDATES existing records.
http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/so-you-want-to-read-csv-files-huh/

FYI, BULK INSERT only works if the files are located on the same disks as the SQL Server instance.  My company understandably won't grant me access to the local drives of the SQL Server, so I will have to test this at home tonight to get you a working example to work with.

Comment: This is nice, but I don't think it applies on the import of a CSV file, or am I mistaken?

Comment: I apologize, I failed to see in your original post that you were importing from CSV.  This link might offer a solution.  http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/so-you-want-to-read-csv-files-huh/  Select the CSV into a Common Table Expression then do the Merge.  I'm going to update my answer to include this link as well.